# What is the difference between 3 and 4 Pin IEC320 C14 Power Sockets?

Tags: switches, ac, connector, mains

What is the difference between 3 and 4 Pin IEC320 C14 Power Sockets?

Looking at the picture attached from [reseller](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/3-Pin-IEC320-C14-Inlet-Module-Plug-Fuse-Switch-Male-Power-Socket-10A-250V-UK/352347144406?_trkparms=aid%3D555017%26algo%3DPL.CASSINI%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20170907081254%26meid%3D6d54f3d1e1ba47c190e6d1c8058efc2e%26pid%3D100281%26rk%3D8%26rkt%3D12%26%26itm%3D352347144406&_trksid=p2045573.c100281.m3567) I cannot see what the 4th pin serves and I cannot find a description anywhere short of just buying one and figuring it out.

Perhaps the fourth pin functions to be always live even when the switch is off?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the switch is not electrically connected to the socket and fuse.

it also looks like those pins are on the back of the switch.

It's probably isolated and non-isolated switch illumination. the data-sheet will say for sure.

Comment: I cannot find a datasheet however what you say makes sense and that's probably it. non-isolated switch illumination is that just the light can be disabled?

Comment: with three pins the light is common  to one of the switch pins, with 4 pins two pins for the light and 2 for the switch.

Comment: oh I see now thanks.

Comment: No the 4 pin switch is a dual pole on off switch. It must be used to switch both live and neutral, as you have no control over in which way the user has connected the mains plug to wall socket

Comment: @Justme I see yes that makes sense as good extra safety requirement if the live and neutral are incorrectly wired.

Comment: No, I don't mean incorrectly wired. In many countries the mains plug can be in any orientation, so if for example a computer PSU is connected to unearthed plug and switch only cuts neutral, the metal case is live via mains filter caps.

Comment: well, no, the metal case is grounded, and the filter caps are designed to not be dangerous.